# Execute php script with cron job

Tags: php, cron

I have a file on my web server called update.php. In this update.php I have two functions which  run when the page is called / loaded. This page and these functions exist solely for the periodic execution by a cron job.

So far I have been calling update.php with a cron job, which then executes the two functions, which access several 3rd party api's and then does some stuff with my database.

Is there a more efficient way to execute those two functions rather than calling them in update.php and then calling update.php with a cron job?

The two function which run are defined in a file called functions.php which is included in  update.php using require_once('functions.php');

Comment: Thinking of the phrase "If it works, don't fix it"

Comment: Just curious; are you having any problem now with this setup ?

Comment: At the moment it "works" just fine. But I was not sure if as my database grows and the functions have to do more and more things if this would be a sub optimal way of calling the functions. When I load the page update.php manually the script execution time is rather long, not sure if it zips right through it though when its the server aka the cron job calling it.